# Why can't constructors gracefully handle errors?

Tags: c++, exception

I read the following

> The inability to gracefully handle errors in C++ constructors is one
>   good reason to avoid constructors that do more than nothing, and use
>   initialization functions instead. And C++ exceptions are not a
>   graceful way to handle errors, especially in constructors. If your
>   member object constructor throws an exception, and you want to catch
>   it in your constructor, the normally ugly colon syntax gets much
>   uglier.

I would like to know why constructors can't gracefully handle errors ? Constructors can still support try-catch so why is it that constructors can't gracefully handle errors ?

Comment: It depends on the definition of "gracefully", but constructors cannot return, say, a status code what can be checked. So the idiomatic way of signalling failure is to throw an exception. I do not agree that using initialization functions is better. It makes little sense to construct objects that cannot be used straight after construction without a call to some init method. Also, why would you want to catch the exception in your constructor? Better let is propagate and handled where it makes sense. That actually seems quite graceful to me.

Comment: Please, cite your sources. This is FQA (Frequently Questioned Answers) [17.2 How can I handle a constructor that fails?](http://yosefk.com/c++fqa/exceptions.html)

Comment: OK, so the source you got that quote from is a kind of "joke" site which you shouldn't take too seriously.

Comment: That site's just an extended rant about how difficult it is to use C++ if you refuse to use its established idioms. Don't take it seriously. Don't take my [counter-rant](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3171647/errors-in-c-fqa/3172059#3172059) seriously either; that's just what happens if I get bored.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> I would like to know why constructors cant gracefully handle errors ?

They can, by throwing an exception if initialisation fails.

This is far more "graceful" than the suggestion to leave the object in a half-alive state, to be properly initialised by calling a function later. Used correctly<sup>[1]</sup>, exceptions guarantee that the object is either fully initialised, or doesn't exist.

This advice presumably comes from someone who disapproves of the use of exceptions to report error conditions; in which case C++ does indeed become an extremely clumsy language, with no convenient way to express initialisation failure. Fortunately, the use of exceptions is idiomatic among most C++ programmers, so there's usually no need to pay attention to this kind of nonsense.

<sub>[1] Specifically, in conjunction with [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization), to avoid the need to "catch it in your constructor" or anywhere apart from the error handler itself.</sub>

Comment: Subtype polymorphism also becomes a major pain in the lower end if you don't use `virtual` for whatever reason :)

Comment: Point well made. +1. The standard library throws exceptions, so C++ is barely usable without them.

Answer (score 6):

I think *"gracefully handling errors"* is subjective...

Anyway, probably the author is thinking of something like:

```
class X
{
private:
   int * v1; // a vector of int's, dynamically allocated
   int * v2; // another vector of int's, dynamically allocated

public:
    X() 
    {
        v1 = new int[...];
        .... do something

        v2 = new int[...];
        ... If this throws, then v1 is leaked, since destructor is not called for X

        ...
    }
};
```

Actually, I think that if you proper use RAII and RAII building-blocks, there are no problems, and constructor *can* handle errors gracefully (for some meaning of "gracefully").

In the above example, if you replace the raw dynamically-allocated arrays with a **RAII** building-block like `std::vector`, you have no problems, since destructors are called on data members if an exception is thrown in the constructor of class `X` (even if the destructor for `X` is not called):

```
class X
{
private:
   std::vector<int> v1;
   std::vector<int> v2;

public:
    X() 
    {
        v1.resize(...);
        .... do something

        v2.resize(...);
        // If this throws, then v1 is NOT leaked, 
        // since the destructor is called for v1 data member

        ...
    }
};
```

Anyway, there are cases in which you just don't want the constructor to throw, e.g. a file class, in which you can have an `IsOpen()` member function to check if the file was opened successfully in the constructor (instead of having the constructor throwing an exception if file open fails).
This is just a matter of personal design preference.

Comment: *Anyway, there are cases in which you just don't want the constructor to throw, e.g. a file class, in which you can have an `IsOpen()`* worst advice ever. Now your `File` class is both nullable **and** has an interface for handling the file. A much saner design uses **RAII**, and switches the burden of nullity onto, for example, `boost::optional` (or `std::unique_ptr`).

Comment: @MatthieuM.: Returning the "favor", yours is worst advice ever. I'm not religious about exceptions, and there are cases in which you just don't want the constructor to throw. And that's much better than making the code more complex with this dynamic-allocation `unique_ptr` suggestion. File-not-opened can be a perfectly fine state, just like empty `std::vector` is.

Comment: It might have come out more aggressively than I intended, for which I apologize. I do think it is one of the worst advice ever, but I certainly did not mean for you to feel slighted. With that out of the way: it all boils down to invariants. At one extreme of the spectrum, you have a `struct`, with no invariant whatsoever by virtue of all of its members being `public`. There are reasons to use a `struct`, but the lack of invariants is an impediment: every-time you wish to use, you either ensure it is in an expected state or forget (ignore) the issue and brace yourself for the explosion...

Comment: ... then, you have classes presenting more and more guarantees; and you soon realize that the stricter the invariants, the more the type system is assisting you in reasoning about the possible set of states of the program. By arguing against establishing more invariants in the constructor, you are arguing for less assistance from the type system. Certainly, there are difficulties in fitting every possible check into the type system (dependent typing anyone ?), but whenever practical relying on 100% coverage instead of runtime tests (and hope), is certainly better. And it's easy in this case.

Comment: I cannot think of any reason, why I would want a file class to have an isOpen() function or why the constructor should not throw. In case of the successful opening of a file is optional, I can express this with an boost::optional and a try-catch.

Comment: @GrapschKnutsch: [std::ifstream::is_open()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/is_open/)

Comment: @Mr.C64: This might have something to do with this part of the C++ library predating C++ Exception Handling. I don't drive uninitialized cars either.

Comment: Uninitialized is bad, but initialized to an empty/safe state is good. Don't you use `std::vector`? Its default constructor initializes it to an empty vector (which to me is a pretty valid state, just like "closed" file).

Comment: yes -- this notion is sometimes necessary and can be nicely expressed using a boost::optional. No need to bother the user or creator of a file class with this.

Comment: @GrapschKnutsch: Frankly, I'm happy both with the existing interface of `std::vector` (that includes a "non-throwing" empty state) and of file/stream classes (that includes a "non-throwing" closed file state). Anyway, I think it's a matter of personal preference.